# Apache Camel, how to test route with wiretaps?

Tags: apache-camel, junit5

I want to write a test for a route with wireTaps.

```
from("direct:inhouse")
.wireTap("direct:persist")
.process(...)
.unmarshal()
.wireTap("direct:transferToX")
.to("direct:createResponse")
.marshal()
.process()
.wireTap("direct:persist")
```

At some of the endpoints, to which the wireTaps send messages, a uuidService is used to generate UUIDs.
My Test mocks the uuid service, to return an incremented uuid every time it is asked for the next uuid like so "uuid-1", "uuid-2" and so on.

Since the wireTaps are not executed in a guaranteed order, I can't write a stable test to check, whether the messages headers contain the expected UUIDs.

I'm looking for a way to have the wireTap paths executed in the order in which they are defined in the route.

I tried to achieve this with an AdviceWithRouteBuilder which replaces wireTaps() with multicast(),
but found this not to be generic enough, since I have to explicitly define the endpoints for the multicast.
If there was a way to have the multicast send the message to the same endpoint that the wireTap (it replaces) would have used, that could work. But I couldn't find a way to configure that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `executorService` option, you could give the wiretap an executor service that makes it execute synchronously:

```java
.wireTap("direct:persist").executorService(new SynchronousExecutorService())
```

You could also specify the name of the service from the registry, which is looked up at runtime, allowing you to use different implementations for test and production

```java
.wireTap("direct:persist").executorService("mySynchronousExecutorService")
```

Comment: Is there a way to "weave" that into the route definition in a testing context?
I would prefer to not change the production code for that. I had a look at what AdviceWith offers, but could not find any match.

Comment: Yes, the [AdviceWith](https://camel.apache.org/manual/advice-with.html) docs show the various weave methods.

Comment: what I'd like to achieve is to replace any `wireTap("x")` with `wireTap("x").executorService(syncServiceExecutor)`.
Using AdviceWith I can replace all the wireTaps like so
`weaveByType(WireTapDefinition.class).replace()
                                            .wireTap("?")
                                            .executorService(synchExService);`

But how do I know which URI the replaced wireTap used?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your UUID may be simple string (and not a real, well formatted UUID), one alternative could be to make your test order-independant.
For instance, by using bitmask.

3 wiretaps => use a 3-digits mask

```
001 which is 1
010 which is 2
100 which is 4
```

So by adding respectively +1, +2, and +4 in the different wiretap mocks, you could, **whatever the execution order.**

- check all wiretaps were invoked if the final UUID is 7 (=1+2+4)
- know at any moment which have been already invoked (by testing the mask value)